# using python class variables to manage global lists (pools)

Tags: python

I've read a bit on class vs instance variables and seen various posts on implementing the Factory Pattern for what I am trying to do... that said I'm pretty new to Python and was hoping to sanity check this for safety and in general good vs poor design.

I basically want to have a class that I can instantiate on the fly and have it manage its own global list.  So I can refer to any instance of the class and get access to all other instances, if desired.  It seems to me that the benefit of doing this allows any function to get access to the global list (and for the class itself to assign unique identifiers per instance, etc.  All encapsulated in the class.)

Here's a simplified approach I was thinking of taking... is ok form, and/or am I misusing the concept of class variables (in this case my list) in this approach?

Thanks for your advice... of course feel free to point me to other posts that answer this.. I continue to read them all, but am not sure I have found the exact right answer.

Jeff

```
class item(object):

    _serialnumber = -1  # the unique serial number of each item created.

    # I think we refer to this (below) as a class variable in Python? or is it really?  
    # This appears to be the same "item_list" across all instances of "item", 
    # which is useful for global operations, it seems

    item_list = []    

    def __init__(self, my_sn):
        self.item_list.append(self)
        self._serialnumber = my_sn

# Now create a bunch of instances and initialize serial# with i.
# In this case I am passing in i, but my plan would be to have the class automatically
# assign unique serial numbers for each item instantiated.

for i in xrange(100,200):
    very_last_item = item(i)  

# Now i can access the global list from any instance of an item

for i in very_last_item.item_list:
    print "very_last_item i sn = %d" % i._serialnumber
```

Comment: User-defined class names should start with a capital letter: `class Item(object)`. This helps distinguish them from instances (built-in types like `str` and `dict` are well-known enough to not need such visual cues).

Answer (score 1):

You declare your class variables correctly, but you are not using them properly. Don't use the `self` unless you are using an instance variable. what you need to do is:

```
item.item_list.append(self)
item._serialnumber = my_sn
```

by using the class name instead of self you are now using a class variable.

since `_serialnumber is really used for the instance you dont have to declare outside the`**init**`function. Also when reading the instances you can just use`item.item_list`. you dont have to use the`very_last_item`

```
class item(object):



    # I think we refer to this (below) as a class variable in Python? or is it really?  
    # This appears to be the same "item_list" across all instances of "item", 
    # which is useful for global operations, it seems

    item_list = []    

    def __init__(self, my_sn):
        item.item_list.append(self)
        self._serialnumber = my_sn

# Now create a bunch of instances and initialize serial# with i.
# In this case I am passing in i, but my plan would be to have the class automatically
# assign unique serial numbers for each item instantiated.

for i in xrange(1,10):
    very_last_item = item(i)  

# Now i can access the global list from any instance of an item


for i in item.item_list:
    print "very_last_item i sn = %d" % i._serialnumber
```

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful. And yes, I was attempting to append the newly created instance (self) to the class variable.  For some reason, using "self" as the reference was seeming to give me the behavior I wanted, but perhaps there were many copies of the list and not one single shared list across all instances.  I'll given it a whirl.  Thanks again.

Comment: `self` works for access, because the object itself doesn't have an attribute by the same name. Be explicit and use the class name to access class attributes, rather than relying Python's lookup behavior.